# Ruby on Rails multiple ActiveRecord items / View State

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to display the values from two ActiveRecord models in my view object. These models are related in that an `Item` can have many `ItemTags`. My code is described as follows:

Model #1 - **item_tags.rb**

```
 class ItemTags < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :ItemID, :tag
   belongs_to :item
 end
```

Model #2 - **item.rb**

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :visible

   has_many :item_tags

 end
```

I have a controller which has an index method which I define as:

```
 def index
 @item = Item.all
 logger.debug "#{@item.inspect}"

 end
```

When I look at the output in the Console for my item, everything appears to be functioning correctly. The page loads, and the debug information shows that I have **Items**.

```
 #<Item id: 1 ... (etc) >
```

The debug information also tells me that for each item, it appears as if I'm performing a `ItemTags Load`. This all seems to make sense to me, but for some reason I cannot or perhaps have not tried the correct syntax for accessing the **item_tags** on my view page. I would like to know the following:

1. In the console, how can I see what items are being Loaded per each **item_tag**? Again, I can see that the `ItemTags Load` is running on each item, but I'm not seeing any results being displayed in the console.
2. What is the proper syntax for referencing my tags for each item in my view? Some items do not have tags.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you really used `ItemID` in your ItemTag model (as your code says) than the answer is very easy: Use `item_id`.

In the controller I would use the plural `@items` (not a mistake but makes life easier):

```
def index
  @items = Item.all
  logger.debug "#{@items.inspect}"
end
```

In the console you can access the first `Item` by:

```
Item.first
```

And you can access all `item_tags` of the first `Item` by:

```
Item.first.item_tags
```

Have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/activerecord_has_many.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the information and resources, they were very helpful. I was able to resolve my issue!